# Python Guess the Number

Tags: python, integer

(Python Guess the Number)

where this f come from? or what does this f means?

Here is the code:
`guess = int(input(f 'Guess a number between 1 and {x}: '))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a representation called f-string, they started supporting them in Python 3.6

https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 0):

A string with an 'f' in the beginning is called an f-string. It is one of the new python 3.6 features. You can read more about it in these links:

[Tutorial on Python 3's f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

[Official Documentation from python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html)